# EJB Transaction between @LocalBean's methods

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.1

I have a `@Stateless` `@LocalBean` which looks like this

```java
@LocalBean
@Stateless
class TokenBean {

    public Token signOn() {       <--------+
        /* Do some JPA things. */          |
    }                                      |
                                           |
    public Token logIn() {                 |
        /* Do some JPA things. */          |
        return signOn();           --------+
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Within `JTA`, How can I commit the transaction in a method before calling other methods? Do I just have to call `flush()` on the `entityManager`? (Actually I'm doing this)

I tried `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` but I don't think it's not for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entityManager.flush()` should be enough, and it will syncronize all attached (to the current persitence context ) entities to the database.
The `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` will start a new transaction for you for every method you call but it won't commit your data unless you exit the method.